# Upgrading Kotlin Gradle plugins to version 1.7.20 causes Sonarqube scanner to throw IllegalStateException

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, sonarqube

I have Kotlin/Spring Boot project that is using the following Kotlin-Gradle plugins:

```
plugins {
...
    val kotlinVersion = "1.7.20"
    kotlin("jvm") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version kotlinVersion
    kotlin("plugin.allopen") version kotlinVersion
...
}
```

when I run a sonarqube analysis, I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line 106 is out of range in the file src/main/kotlin/com/my/package/Client.kt (lines: 97)
```

Is there an analysis parameter that I am missing here or something else? When I was using version 1.7.10 of the plugins, everything seemed to work fine from a Sonarqube perspective.

Comment: The following analysis parameters configured in our sonar-project.properties: 

sonar.sources=src/main/kotlin
sonar.tests=src/test/kotlin

Comment: Facing the same issue with Kotlin 1.7.20